# I Can´t use dismiss in postExecute

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, dialog

I've been working with *asyncTasks* for a while in my project and I've never had problems but this is driving me crazy.

I have this class that makes a dialog with a kind of a gif in it that simulates an indeterminate progress bar:

```
public class CustomDialogProgressBar {
private Dialog dialog;

/**
 * Instantiates a new Custom dialog progress bar.
 *
 * @param activity the activity
 */
public CustomDialogProgressBar(Activity activity){
    dialog = new Dialog(activity);
}

/**
 * Muestra el diálogo personalizado con ondas
 */
public void showDialogOndas(){
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progressbar_wave);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * Muestra el diálogo personalizado con un plano rotando
 */
public void showDialogCuadrado(){
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progressbar_cuadrado);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * Finaliza el diálogo, lo mata
 */
public void endDialog(){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

I use this dialogs as a progressBar, so I call the method **showDialogoOndas** in the **preExecute** and then I call the **endDialog** method in the **postExecute**.

Just like this:

```
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        customDialogProgressBar.showDialogOndas();
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Receta> recetas) {
        super.onPostExecute(recetas);
        try {
            myHelper.cerrarConexion();
            mainSr.crearAdapter(recetas);
            customDialogProgressBar.endDialog();
            Log.d("AAAAAAAA", "tiempo en AsyncTask: " + recetas.get(0).getTiempo());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d("SQL", "Error al cerrar la bbdd");
        }
    }
```

But the Dialog stays in an infinite loop and the dismiss is neverCalled, I've alredy checked that the **onPostExecuted** method is called.

I think the problem is because the async task is attached to a fragment because I tryed this on an Activity and it works. The fragment is part of a bottomNavigation.

Thx for your help.

**EDIT**

Debugger on the try:

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9JuV.png)

Comment: yes you are right it could be a problem of context. because when you are creating the progress bar you are passing a reference of the activity that is creating the progress bar. and when from fragment you are trying to close it you must refer to the same context

Comment: is this executed Log.d("SQL", "Error al cerrar la bbdd");?

Comment: but I´m giving the same reference of the activity to the constructor of the *CustomDialogProgressBar *, so I don't know what to do... In the onCreateView method of the fragment: **customDialogProgressBar = new CustomDialogProgressBar(getActivity());**

Comment: @Raghunandan nope the sql code works great

Comment: can you debug with a break point at start of try block and step through to see whats happening